# Key(s) to change layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I get used to the following combination to change keyboard layouts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>7</kbd> change to english
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>8</kbd> change to russian
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>9</kbd> change to chinese

How to do it with Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to `System Settings -> Keyboard` and then open Shortcuts tab you can setup custom shortcuts for performing the change.

You can add new shortcut and use the command `setxkbd` to switch layout. If you run `setxkbd us` your keyboard will be set to US layout. You'll have to look up the rest of layout codes.

Comment: Thanks for answering, the only thing is that 'setxkbd us' command for new shortcut doesn't work for me. I've googled for the keyboard layout switch shortcut, and found that others recommended to use 'setxkbmap us' or 'setxkbmap -layout us'. Both options doesn't work for me as well.